# Itext Sharp - multithreading issues

Tags: c#, itext

> : Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory. The I/O package is not thread safe by default. In multithreaded applications, a stream must be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader.

Reading online, it looks like iText PDF sharp is threadsafe (but maybe I am wrong!).

I get the above exception when running Itext inside of a parallel for loop.

```
 iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(path);

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        Parallel.For(1, pdfReader.NumberOfPages + 1, page =>
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

                text.Add(currentText);
            }
        );
        pdfReader.Close();
```

Comment: make sure that text object is accessed more than one thread.. use concurrency lock(myObj){ text.Add(currentText))};  .. remember these are not sequential task so that pages text will be added randomly..

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"! And please rework your title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a single thread can access the **same** document at the same time. iText(Sharp) is thread safe in the sense that several threads can create and manipulate **different** documents concurrently.

Comment: If you use a FileStream with shared read access when initializing the PdfReader class, multiple threads can access the same document.